# Using accessor methods when displaying randomized objects to the user?

Tags: java

For my class I have to make a program that will quiz the user on 3 multiple-choice, Java-related questions. Each time the program executes, the questions should be displayed to the user in a random order.

The foundation for a question is made with a Question class, which I have essentially "finished" and the file has compiled. However, my teacher suggested us to use accessor methods which will return the different fields to main. Normally, this would be no problem because there is only one definite object to return to main. But how are you supposed to return a variable if you're not sure what object the program will display?

I tried to put the actual questions into the Question class instead of my main class using code such as this, which would render the need for accessors obsolete since everything would be in the same class.

```
question = this.question;
        this.question = ("Which of these is not a primitive data type?");

        choiceA = this.choiceA;
        this.choiceA = ("string");
```

However, to make the code in the Question class less repetitive, I moved the actual questions to my main class, so accessors are still necessary. I am using an arrayList and then Collections.Shuffle in my main class which have the questions inputted into them, and then randomized. I want to print the randomized question to the user, but to do so I still need the accessors. At this point, though, the code is already randomized. I'm not sure how to get the data from the Question class that corresponds to the right randomized question, and then display that to the user (hopefully this makes sense). Here's the Question class so far:

```
// declare fields for the class
    private String question; // ex: "Which is not a primitive data type?"
    private String choiceA; // ex: "string"
    private String choiceB; // ex: "boolean"
    private String choiceC; // ex: "long"
    private String choiceD; // ex: "char"
    private String correctAns; // ex: "string"

    // constructor for the question
    public Question(String question, String choiceA, String choiceB, String choiceC, String choiceD, String correctAns)
    {
        question = this.question;

        choiceA = this.choiceA;

        choiceB = this.choiceB;

        choiceC = this.choiceC;

        choiceD = this.choiceD;

        correctAns = this.correctAns;
    }

    // accessor method for retrieving the question
    public String getQuestion()
    {
        return question;
    }

    // accessor method for retrieving the first choice of the question
    public String getChoiceA()
    {
        return choiceA;
    }

    // accessor method for retrieving the second choice of the question
    public String getChoiceB()
    {
        return choiceB;
    }

    // accessor method for retrieving the third choice of the question
    public String getChoiceC()
    {
        return choiceC;
    }

    // accessor method for retrieving the fourth choice of the question
    public String getChoiceD()
    {
        return choiceD;
    }

    // accessor method for retrieving the correct answer to the question
    public String getCorrectAns()
    {
        return correctAns;
    }
```

If this helps, here are the guidelines for the project: "Create a Question class that you can instantiate into three Question objects in your main method. Store the Question objects in an array or arraylist.  Then play the Questions in a random order each time you play the program." There's no explicit direction that we write the actual questions (ex: "What is not a primitive data type?") in the main class or the question class, but I'm still not sure which one will be most efficient.

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**

My desired output will be three questions in a random order like such:

**Which of these is not a Java key word?**

- A) switch
- B) keyboard
- C) float
- D) true

**What must a switch-case statement end with?**

- A) switch
- B) break
- C) continue
- D) else

**Which of these is not a primitive data type?**

- A) String
- B) Boolean
- C) Long
- D) Char

Each time the program runs, the user answers these Questions in a different order. Using the accessors, these random fields ("which of these is not a primitive data type," and then all the subsequent answers) must all be returned to the main class in a different order. That's what I'm not sure how to do because accessors usually access a definitive value.

Also, here's the code I have that is creating the question objects and putting them in the arrayList. I haven't actually put in the actual data yet but this is essentially what it's supposed to look like.

```
// Create an ArrayList which will store the Question objects    
    ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();

    // Add 3 questions to the ArrayList using a for-loop
    for (int counter = 0; i < 3; counter++)
    {
        questionList.add(new Question(String question, String choiceA, String choiceB, String choiceC, String choiceD, String correctAns));
    }

    // randomize the order of the questions in the ArrayList
    Collections.shuffle(questionList);
```

Comment: I'm not yet sure I understand what you're asking.  Can you please provide sample input and desired output from your program?  I'm thinking that you should have a variable that you set to the choice/question you chose to present to the user.  Then, you can just use that variable to access the specific question you want to "access".  But I'm not sure from what you show and say if that's your issue.  Please consider providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we have a complete set of code to look at, even if it doesn't yet do quite what you want.

Comment: I just made an edit. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: So instead of using a loop to add to your ArrayList, create an instance of Question and populate it by passing actual values (strings with the values you want in the question) to the constructor.  Then add that instance to the ArrayList.  Repeat two more times for the other questions...

Answer (score 1):

In the Constructor, your assignments are backwards.  You're currently replacing the passed in parameters with the stored, class members.  Switch them around so that the class members are assigned the values that were passed in:

```
// constructor for the question
public Question(String question, String choiceA, String choiceB, String choiceC, String choiceD, String correctAns)
{
    this.question = question;
    this.choiceA = choiceA;
    this.choiceB = choiceB;
    this.choiceC = choiceC;
    this.choiceD = choiceD;
    this.correctAns = correctAns;
}
```

The "this" refers to the current instance of the class, thus the variable name after the "." is a class member.

Comment: To be of more assistance, we'd need to see how you are creating and storing instances of your Question class.  Then we can see how should be picking one at random.

Comment: I just added the part of the program where I'm putting the objects into an arrayList. Hopefully that will help!